# PHP user authentication and security methods: LDAP-AD, and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, security, authentication, ldap

I've come across a few questions regarding integrating user authentication via LDAP Active Directory server to a company website. The website is mainly used internally to give secure access to files/PDFs. The site is accessible outside our network, as certain customers also need to be able to view/upload files for their orders and verification. We do have an SSL cert in place for secure access to the site, for internal and external.

At this time, the site uses [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) for password handling, while storing user information in an MS SQL Server database. Users who need access to the site are added to this database, with account level registered and phpass handling the password aspect. This method is pretty secure, and works fine for current usage (internal employees, segregated data for outside customers). However it also introduces more points of failure for the entire system. IE: Additional passwords for users to remember (or forget) and additional account management overhead for the admin.

In planning to streamline the authentication for the site, I've been tasked with integrating Active directory user information to be be utilized for login. This will work fine for the employees of our company, because they already have an AD account. However, this **will not** work for outside vendors or customers, because they do NOT have an AD account (and should not) to authenticate against.

This leads me to believe the easiest solution is to have a 'main' form of authentication (against AD) and a fallback against the already created SQL user DB. Users who come back as in AD, use those credentials, else search the SQL DB for the user (which would contain any non AD accounts we needed).

**Questions:**

- Is the above outlined method of verification a logical and secure plan?? *If not, what should I be doing instead?*
- How does one secure against LDAP attack/brute force?

  - In PHP/SQL, utilizing parameterized/typecast queries, account lockouts/timeouts, generic error messages, proper password hashing methods, etc - add up for securing the database and forced login attempts
  - For ldap_bind, username and password are sent across network to LDAP server in the clear??
- As this login is for the entire network, how can I ensure my login/site is NOT the weakest link of security, or causing undue ease of access to password information?

*Note: This was posted on StackOverflow and not ServerFault, because my issue is with programming the PHP website for security. My question relates foremost to the website access, restriction, and permission issues of user login WHILE authenticating to AD or backup database.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That they don't have LDAP acounts currently is not a reason for making a two-tier application. This is not just twice as vulnerable - since by implementing your own authentication back end you also need to implement all the user admin that goes along with that. Just add accounts for external users but don't allow them access to any of your workstations.

Comment: I am accepting your answer even though it doesn't *techincally* answer the question. Additional admin overhead and point of failures/attack vectors with having two user databases is not ideal. I've added the external accounts to AD with a very locked down GP which also denies local logins and other unneeded network access.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Drupal, the LDAP authentication module does almost the same thing: If it can't find a Drupal account for the user (i.e. for your contractors) it goes to LDAP and tries to authenticate to there. In the case of LDAP, it doesn't ever store the password in its own database. So yes, your plan has been done before and seems to be more or less accepted. I once made a drupal module that used the drupal logins, then a CAS system with an LDAP fallback if the CAS system wasn't online.

Securing an LDAP server against brute force would normally be done by domain-level whitelisting. I work at a university which uses the LDAP server for most everything and some information is in the public domain while some is hidden so that they comply with various federal laws. Certain information can only be accessed by requests from the university network while being bound to the server with an account with sufficient privileges to access the information (i.e. emails, unlisted addresses, etc). As long as your passwords are good and changed regularly it should be ok. You could always restrict using LDAP for authentication to certain services only and make either your website or the LDAP server (I don't know if it could be configured like this...but who knows? it could maybe) track the number of failed login attempts and make the person wait 5 minutes or something after 5 failed attempts.

When communicating to the server, you should use ldaps to keep from transmitting in the clear. Unless you are using the Zend server for MAC this works quite well (the particular version of PHP that it has doesn't like ldaps and will hang the server) and will keep people from sniffing your traffic and making your website the weakest link. Also, never store people's passwords on your site and make sure that https is being used when they are on the login page.